# Sprout Reports settings template no longer functioning

Tags: multi-site, plugin-sproutreports

I'm returning to a Sprout report on a project that was idle for a few years due to Covid. I was puzzled as to why both my settings and report templates were yielding nothing. The only change in the interim was adding additional sites to this install.

Answer (score 1):

The fix was elusive but ultimately simple. **In order for reports queries to work on a multi-site Craft 3 install, you must reference the site slug or site ID.**

GOOD

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('blat').siteId(2).all() %}
```

BAD

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('blat').all() %}
```